# How do I decrypt a file with mcrypt?

Tags: encryption

I have the following:

- mcrypt installed
- a file with a .zip.nc extension
- a password

How do I use mcrypt to decrypt the file? The man page isn't very helpful.

I've tried

```
mcrypt -k password file.zip.nc > output
```

But nothing seems to be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

`mcrypt -d file.zip.nc`

You should then be prompted for your password and the file should decrypt.